# How to receive notification when the application is closed?

Tags: android, notifications

I'm making an android application, and I want to receive notifications when the application is closed, how can I do that? I've read also other posts where people ask it but i can't understand how to make it work, could you please try to explain this better?

I've also tried to make a countdownTimer and make the application do something when the timer reaches the 0 but it didn't work, 'cause obviusly when I close the application, I close the timer too.

Comment: What does "receive notifications" mean, specifically?

Comment: I wanted the application to send me push notification, like in Clash of Clans when the application reminds you that the army is ready.

Comment: Like a "reminder" that tells you have to open it. I don't know if you understand.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/background

Comment: Thanks a lot man, really helpful.

Comment: Sorry, disregard that duplicate suggestion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code to make in app notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) // notification icon
            .setContentTitle("Notification!") // title for notification
            .setContentText("Hello word") // message for notification
            .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Okay, I've done this too, the problem is that I want show this notification every 3 days. How do I do that?

Comment: ok,you have to  save current time to Sharedpreferences  after that you have to calculate how many time spent since Sharedpreference time.like this if(sharedpreferencetime == current time){showNotification()}